# If $f$ is separately holomorphic on $\Omega$ then $f\in\mathcal{C}^0(\bar\Omega)\Leftrightarrow f\in L^1(\Omega)$

Tags: cv.complex-variables, several-complex-variables

Let $\Omega\subseteq\Bbb C^2$ be open bounded (and connected), $f:\Omega\to\Bbb C$ separately holomorphic (i.e. $f$ is holomorphic in each variable when the other is fixed).

Hartogs theorem is not allowed, so we can't say $f$ is holomorphic on $\Omega$.

Now I think that in this case $f$ is continous in $\bar\Omega$ iff $f$ is integrable in $\Omega$. In other words $f\in\mathcal{C}^0(\bar\Omega)\Leftrightarrow f\in L^1(\Omega)$.

Clearly one implication ($\Rightarrow$) is always true. But the other?

At the moment I can't get no proof nor counterexamples. Can someone help me? Many thanks

Comment: you are asking integrable implies and is implied by continuous. which is a good question, depends which field you are looking @.

Comment: What do you mean by "Hartog's theorem is not allowed"?

Comment: I mean that we can't use it; we can't say "the Hartogs thm hyp are ok so we can say $f$ is holomorphic". However, I don't think this is a restriction. Maybe I can delete it.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry: I'm looking for $\Bbb C$; the functions we're dealing with are $f:\Omega\to\Bbb C$, where $\Omega\subseteq\Bbb C^2$, and it is open bounded and connected.

Comment: $f(w,z)=1/z$ on $|w|,|z|<1$, $z\not= 0$ is a counterexample.

Comment: Many thanks! Write it as an answer, I'd be happy to give you the points you deserve!

Comment: @Joe : Thanks, but this doesn't seem to have enough substance for an answer.

Comment: @ChristianRemling: I agree with you, yet maybe you could consider making this a short answer just for the sake of closing the question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not work if $L^1$ refers to area measure: the function $f(w,z)=1/z$ on (let's say) $|w|,|z|<1$, $z\not= 0$ is a counterexample.